# How to modify emulex FC HBA blocksize?

Tags: networking, san

I have an Emulex FC HBA (LPe111), the current block size is 512K. I want to change it to 1MB, but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you mean the ExtTransferSize option. See https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12356360